# Ajax post does not give value to php file, post becomes get

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this ajax function for login.

Edit: I just noticed that this server runs php7 while other server where the login does work uses php5. What has changed in php that this script doesn't work anymore?

Edit 2: Looks like the server request method isn't post but changed to get, why?

**Solution: needed to remove the .php from `url: "./ajaxcall/login.php",` because I use pretty url htaccess.**

```js
var InName = $('#InName').val();
        var InPass = $('#InPass').val();
        alert(InName);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./ajaxcall/login.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {InName:InName, InPass:InPass},
            error: function (request, error) {
                console.log(arguments);
                alert("Inlog Can't do because: " + error);
            },
            success : function(data){
                if (data.code == "200"){
                    $("#InErEr").html(data.msg);
                    //window.location.reload(true);
                } else {
                    $("#InErEr").html(data.msg);
                    $('.lds-dual-ring').animate({opacity: 0}, 300);
                }
            }
        });
```

On the `alert(InName);` I get the correct value of the username. But when I check in my php file `$_POST['InName']` it is empty.

Part of php file

```php
include('../config.php');

if(empty($_POST['InName'])) {
    $Ierror = 'Username is required.';
}
if($_POST['InPass'] == '') {
    $Ierror = 'Password is required.';
}
$username = $_POST['InName'];
$passwordL = $_POST['InPass'];
// count user in between //
if($Inlognumber_of_rows == 0) {
    $Ierror = 'Username not found.';
} else {
    // password check //
    if(password_verify($salty_pass, $hashed_password)) {
    } else {
        $Ierror = 'Password incorrect.';
    }
}
if ($Ierror == '') {
// do login //
} else {
    $showerror = '<span style="color:#F00;">'.$Ierror.$username.$passwordL.$_POST['InName'].$_POST['InPass'].'</span>';
    echo json_encode(['code'=>404, 'msg'=>$showerror]);
    exit;
}
```

In the return message, $showerror I only get, Username not found, without the posted values. So the login is not working because of empty values? User is also present in the database of course. I also don't get the empty $_POST errors. So to cap up, in javascript I get the correct value for InName but not in php.

Comment: Your code works... what are you passing as the value of InName? is it a string? I changed the values of the InName and InPass to strings and sent the post to a file which save the $_POST as a json and it arrived good... : {"InName":"something","InPass":"morething"} , I did receive an alert of error that has nothing to do with the post .. you are not returning the correct response I think

Comment: I'm happy you tell me the code is good!  I thought I was going mental. I used this code before this week and it works. Trying to pass username from text input field. "you are not returning the correct response" I don't get it? '$_POST['InName']' should return that value.?

Comment: Check out the example in my answer.... basically you are catching wrong error in you post... try this example of ajax post where the error and or second function are much  clearer to understand... :)

Comment: But I still don't get it why my script isn't working while it does on another project? I gonna try your script later this day. But I'm afraid it also gonna show that the post isn't working. And I still can't see why?

Comment: Regarding the PHP versions, I can't spot anything in your code, that would work differently under PHP 7, than it used to under PHP 5.

Comment: @CBroe I have installed the exact same script on other server that runs php5 and there the login does work. It's a brain breaker I also can't figure it out what causes this, already trying for 2 days straight to fix it.

Comment: Make a debug output of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`, and check if that actually contains POST.

Comment: @CBroe `$test = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];` It shows GET, but the weird thing is, `$showerror = '<span style="color:#F00;">'.$Ierror.$username.$passwordL.$_GET['InName'].$_POST['InPass'].'</span>';` The `$_GET['InName']` also is not showing any value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: needed to remove the .php from url: "./ajaxcall/login.php", because I use pretty url htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

You are close but your error catch is not correct ... try this (Jquery):

```js
var InName = 'something';
var InPass = 'morething';
$.post("./ajaxcall/login.php", {
    InName: InName,
    InPass: InPass
  }, function(data, status) {
    console.log(data, status);
  }).done(function() {
    alert("second success");
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert("error");
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert("finished");
  });
```

on your php file just do print_r($_POST); and you will receive this in your console...:

```html
Array
(
    [InName] => something
    [InPass] => morething
)
 success
```

Basically you were trying to print the error where you should have consoled log the request.responeText...

A good trick to know if posts arrived to the php even if the console.log won't show is doing this in the php file:

```html
<?php
print_r($_POST) ;

$newfile = fopen('newfile.txt','a');
fwrite($newfile,json_encode($_POST));
fclose($newfile);
```

This will print and also store on a local file the post data....

Comment: As expected with you code it's still not working. I get an empty `Array
() {"code":404,"msg":"<span style=\"color:#F00;\">Username is required.Password is required.Username not found.<\/span>"} success` Also in the newfile.txt its empty `[]`